# if i search for the document sets ,then only document set should come in search results not his documents

Tags: search, search-results, document-set, enterprise-search, fast

My scenario is.

We need the document sets to appear in the search. It should just show as a document set. All document under the document set should not show.

The issue i am facing right now is , if the document set contains the documents with the same/partly same name ,then they also appear in the search results. So , i have to limit that.

& also i want to do this only for specific document library , Means if the document set i am searching is in that specific library than only this condition should work.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to set search scope with content type as document set.

Else you can try to create a view, filtered as Document Set items only. Then create scope from it.